# Column constraint based on values in another column

Tags: postgresql, database-design, trigger, constraint, check-constraints

I have a PostgreSQL table `phase_steps`, with the following example rows:

```
phase_step_id|step_type|step_status|
-------------+---------+-----------+
            1| RESEARCH|           |
            2|   SURVEY|           |
```

Update values to the `step_status` column depend on what value the
`step_type` value is.
When `step_type` is 'RESEARCH', only values of 'COMPLETE' or 'INCOMPLETE' can be entered for `step_status` values.
When `step_type` is 'SURVEY', only values of 'ASSIGNED' or 'NOT ASSIGNED' can be entered for `step_status` values.

I tried to manage the 'RESEARCH' `step_status` constraints with this procedure:

```
create or replace function insert_step_status_value() returns trigger as $$
    begin
        if (new.step_status != 'COMPLETE') or (new.step_status != 'INCOMPLETE')
        from phase_steps where step_type = 'RESEARCH'
        then
            raise exception 'Status value not in range for this phase step';
        end if;
        return new;
    end;
$$ language plpgsql;

create trigger check_step_status_value before update on phase_steps
for each row execute procedure insert_step_status_value();
```

However, an insert like

```
update jobs.phase_steps
set step_status_lu = 'INCOMPLETE'
where phase_step_id = 1;
```

gives an error:

> ```
> SQL Error [P0001]: ERROR: Status value not in range for this phase step
> Where: PL/pgSQL function insert_step_status_value() line 6 at RAISE
> ```

Thoughts?

Comment: Please start with your version of Postgres and the exact table definition (`CREATE TABLE` statement showing data types and constraints).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A [`CHECK` constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-CHECK-CONSTRAINTS) does the job. Simpler, cheaper and more reliable than a trigger.

To enforce the listed combinations, your table definition could look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE jobs.phase_steps (
  phase_step_id integer GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
, step_type     text
, step_status   text
, CONSTRAINT    step_status_for_step_type CHECK (
      step_type = 'RESEARCH' AND step_status IN ('COMPLETE', 'INCOMPLETE')
   OR step_type = 'SURVEY'   AND step_status IN ('ASSIGNED', 'NOT ASSIGNED')
      )
);
```

Or a simpler equivalent:

```
, CONSTRAINT step_status_for_step_type CHECK (
       (step_type, step_status)
   IN (('RESEARCH', 'COMPLETE')
     , ('RESEARCH', 'INCOMPLETE')
     , ('SURVEY'  , 'ASSIGNED')
     , ('SURVEY'  , 'NOT ASSIGNED')))
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/3OnhuwWC)

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-DESCRIPTION)

> There are two ways to define constraints: table constraints and column
> constraints. A column constraint is defined as part of a column
> definition. A table constraint definition is not tied to a particular
> column, and it can encompass more than one column.

Operator precedence works in our favor, no additional parentheses required.
Allows no other combined values for `(step_type, step_status)` - **except for `null` values**. A `CHECK` constraint is passed if the expression evaluates to `true` or `null`.

You may want to add a `NOT NULL` constraint to `step_type`, then `step_status` can still be `null`, and `step_type` can be anything (but `null`) in this case. But if `step_status` has a value, the combination has to pass the check.

**Or**, to also disallow any other value for `step_type`:

```
ALTER TABLE phase_steps
  DROP CONSTRAINT step_status_for_step_type
, ADD  CONSTRAINT step_status_for_step_type CHECK (
         CASE step_type WHEN 'RESEARCH' THEN step_status IN ('COMPLETE', 'INCOMPLETE')
                        WHEN 'SURVEY'   THEN step_status IN ('ASSIGNED', 'NOT ASSIGNED')
                        ELSE false END);
```

Now any other value for `step_type` (incl. `null`) reaches the `ELSE` branch and makes the check `false`. (But `null` in `step_status` still passes.)

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/3OnhuwWC)

Comment: Thanks, Erwin. Your answer(s) always set the Gold Standard!